# Equivalent of \glsresetall in glossaries-extra

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I have switched from the `glossaries` package to `glossaries-extra` to enable some link counting in my document.
However, now my `\glsresetall` commands no longer work.
What is the equivalent in `glossaries-extra`?

Thanks for any help.

**Edit: Minimum Working Example**

Here is a MWE. I've included a toggle (`use-glos-extra`) to show the working version using `glossaries`, and the desired version with `glossaries-extra`.

At the start of both chapters, it should read

`Discussing artificial intelligence (AI), then talking about AI`

But, using `glossaries-extra`, both chapters immediately read

`Discussing AI, then talking about AI`.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\providetoggle{use-glos-extra}
\settoggle{use-glos-extra}{true}
\iftoggle{use-glos-extra}{
    % GLOSSARIES-EXTRA package
    \usepackage{glossaries-extra}
}
{
    %% GLOSSARIES pacakge
    \usepackage{glossaries}
}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{ai}{AI}{artificial intelligence}
\preto\chapter\glsresetall

\begin{document}
\printglossaries

\chapter{First chapter}
Discussing \gls{ai},  then talking about \gls{ai}.

\chapter{Second chapter}
Discussing \gls{ai},  then talking about \gls{ai}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange, because I used it several times with `glossaries-extra` and cannot remember any problems with it. So, do you have a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) where we can recreate this error?

Comment: Thanks @venez, I have added a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restore the behavior of `\glsreset` commands with `glossaries-extra` using `\RestoreAcronyms`. However, this will disable some functionality of `glossaries-extra`. Code:

```
\makeglossaries
\RestoreAcronyms
\newacronym{ai}{AI}{artificial intelligence}
\preto\chapter\glsresetall
```

Alternatively, you can load `glossaries-extra` with the `[acronym]` option, and set an explicit acronym style. Code:

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
```

In this case `\RestoreAcronyms` is not needed.

For more information about the effects of both options see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.pdf) of `glossaries-extra`, section 2.9 *Acronym Style Modifications*.

Comment: \RestoreAcronyms solved my problem, thanks!